# How to prove this inequality with absolute value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value

For every $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} $

$$
|x|+|y|+|z| \leq |x+y-z|+|x-y+z|+|-x+y+z|
$$
I tried to prove it by cases, but I have troubles when the three numbers have the same sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 
$$\sum_{cyc}|x+y-z|=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(|x+y-z|+|x+z-y|\right)\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}|x+y-z+x+z-y|=\sum_{cyc}|x|$$

Answer (score 1):

if all of the numbers are positive then the left is $x+y+z$ and the right is at least $x+y+z$ (that is what you get when you remove the absolute values).

Notice that if all three are negative all of the expressions have the same values as with $(-x,-y,-z)$.

Comment: And I suppose checking all of the in between $(\pm x,\pm y,\pm z)$ result similarly.

Comment: well, he said he was having trouble with the case in which they all had the same sign.

Comment: The right side may be less than that. Consider the case when the three numbers are equal to 1, the right side is not 6, but 3.

Comment: @JJmz fixed, thanks.